# \[exec\] POD document had syntax errors at /usr/bin/pod2man line 71

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, xuggle

I hope you are fine and all is well,

I'm trying to install Xuggle on Ubuntu 14.04. 
 I'm using

- g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4
- Linux xxxxx-HP-EliteBook-820-G1 3.13.0-67-generic #110-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 23 13:24:41 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- java version "1.7.0_85"
  OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.1) (7u85-2.6.1-5ubuntu0.14.04.1)
  OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.85-b03, mixed mode)

Unfortunately I have got the folowing messages:

```
 [exec] HTML    doc/platform.html
 [exec] POD doc/ffmpeg.pod
 [exec] MAN doc/ffmpeg.1
 [exec] doc/ffmpeg.pod around line 11306: Non-ASCII character seen before =encoding in '8�8'. Assuming UTF-8
 [exec] make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/tiberkak/xuggle-xuggler/build/native/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/captive/ffmpeg/csrc'
 [exec] make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/tiberkak/xuggle-xuggler/build/native/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/captive/ffmpeg'
 [exec] make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/tiberkak/xuggle-xuggler/build/native/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/captive'
 [exec] POD document had syntax errors at /usr/bin/pod2man line 71.
 [exec] make[3]: *** [doc/ffmpeg.1] Error 255
 [exec] make[2]: *** [all-local] Error 2
 [exec] make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
 [exec] make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

BUILD FAILED
/home/tiberkak/xuggle-xuggler/mk/buildtools/buildhelper.xml:1192: exec returned: 2

Total time: 12 minutes 17 seconds

I hope someone can help me
Regards
Allal

Answer (score 0):

Reading a bit the error message, it looks like an encoding error. 
Either you are running on Windows and the code you downloaded has been modified or something else fishy happened.

In any case, simply trying to open the **doc/ffmpeg.pod** file at line 11306 and replacing the character that looks strange should fix the issue.

This is only an error when the documentation get built, so I assume the actual compilation of Xuggler went fine.

Hope this helps, 
Cheers, 
Julien